# Is there a way to generate a list of override field values using Bloomberg OpenAPI?

Tags: python, bloomberg, openapi

For instance, if I wanted to query prescriptions in a specific drug market, I can specify the market for e.g. 10MG pills. Is there a way to pull the list of all possible drug strengths for this field?

```
        request.append("securities", "RX_00000 Comdty")
        request.append("fields", 'TOTAL_RETAIL_RX')
        request.set("startDate", "20160101")
        request.set("endDate", "20160331")
        request.set("periodicitySelection", "MONTHLY")
        overrides = request.getElement("overrides")
        override1 = overrides.appendElement()
        override_objects['DRUG_STRENGTH_OVERRIDE'].setElement("value", "10MG")
```

Or in Excel:

```
=BDH("RX_00000 Comdty","TOTAL_RETAIL_RX",20160101,20160331,"per","M","DRUG_STRENGTH_OVERRIDE","10MG")
```

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: This is a good point, I've heard how helpful they can be though it's not something I typically even think of

Comment: Helpdesk didn't know, I'm guessing it's probably not possible, rather disappointing